# Combine content of columns with dynamic list in power query

Tags: powerquery

I use the following code to try to combine the columns, but I can't get the content to combine. Only the headers.

```
Table.AddColumn(Source2, "CombineColumn1", each Text.Combine(List1, ":"), type text)
```

[image]
[image]

I tried to just replace the headers from the combine function in power query with the list. I also used [index] and the column header in the code. I get errors in the CombinedColumn1 or just the headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
= Table.CombineColumns(
    Source2,
    List1[Lijst],
    Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(":", QuoteStyle.None),
    "CombineColumn1"
)
```

Or

```
= Table.CombineColumns(
    Source2,
    {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"},
    Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(":", QuoteStyle.None),
    "CombineColumn1"
)
```

Comment: The first code works for me, but without the [Lijst]. This solution really helps me a lot. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

To combine all columns into one, add column ... custom column .. with

```
= Text.Combine(List.Transform(Record.FieldValues(_), each Text.From(_)),":")
```

Comment: Nice - watchout for NULL values as these will be omitted. Do a `Replace Values` beforehand to replace NULL with "", if you want to preserve the number of items eg: `a::c` instead of just `a:c`

Comment: Unfortunateley this doesn't work for me. I need it to be from a list, not all columns. I've seen this code before. I like it. I'll experiment with it. Thanks tho!